# How to create a Samsung emulator

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Currently in Android Studio, there is no option to use an Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro tablet AVD. I have tried going through this [documentation](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095), but it does not work - there is no option for "default skin". Can you show me how to install this avd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to scroll down on the left side of the "Configure Hardware Profile" page. Please have a look at the attached image[image]

Answer (score 2):

I hope you already have downloaded this skin provided by you.
Though you can download [Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 8.4 Emulator Skin](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000244&pi=1&ps=10&pb=Y&ct=CT350000&sc=)

And extract that in proper directory like below [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXWfK.jpg)

And follow as guided your "Documentation" link

Hope it will help you

Answer (score -1):

You need to too download proper drivers for your device OEM USB Drivers

[Android OEM USB Drivers](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjSkoewuJDLAhUqG5oKHZsrCmYQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftools%2Fextras%2Foem-usb.html&usg=AFQjCNHDtVajeqxRSEkx04HVrfeAcF-dGw)